# Can I take a small aluminum drying rack on plane?

Tags: hand-luggage

I have a small drying rack that is almost the dimensions of 28 inch bag. It just will take too much space if fitted in bag.

Can I just take it as a carry on with me?!

Comment: A 28" bag is usually quite a bit larger than carry-on size (usually about 9x14x22 or so depending on airline). Is the rack even within the size limitations?

Comment: Also note that policies vary considerably between airlines. Some are extremely strict and allow only a single carry-on item, even if all items combined would still fit in the allowed size.

Comment: @ZachLipton It is in the dimensions but I thought I just hold it with me instead of fitting it in any bag as it will be inserted will angle. So, I will take half of the 28" for nothing and it's pretty thin and light

Comment: @jcron Yes right. But  it feels not a big deal to stop me to take it as separate item as I think it is not huge

Comment: @Omar113 What are the actual dimensions of the rack, what airline are you flying on, and what class? Will you have this in addition to a bag in the cabin, or does the bag go in checked luggage? What are the dimensions of the bag?

Comment: Besides the sizes, would this be rejected as a 'blunt object, can be used as a weapon'?

Comment: You're not allowed to keep anything on your lap so it would have to go into an overhead compartment or under the seat in front of you.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to look at the airline you're travelling with, and identify their cabin luggage requirements.  It's unlikely to be considered a weapon, but most airlines have luggage dimension requirements so that they can fit in overhead luggage or under the seat in front of you.  Due to different configurations, each airline might have its own policy.

If you want to be absolutely certain, email the airline asking, so that you have a written confirmation before you board your flight.